# Can't access microsoft.com and skype.com web site after installing VS2013 Preview

Tags: windows

Recently i installed Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Preview Ultimate on Windows 7. Everything went smoothly except now i can't access www.microsoft.com and www.skype.com anymore. Tried latest IE10 and FireFox, both show blank page when accessing the above mentioned web sites. Firefox in its left bottom corner shows that it is waiting for ajax.aspnetcdn.com.

I'd really like not to reinstall OS on my machine, so i'd appreciate any idea how to fix this. For myself i tried to stop Firewall service and disable MS Security Essentials runtime protection, neither helped.

PS: I can access www.microsoft.com and www.skype.com from another machine in the same local network

**UPDATE:** i am using tfs.visulstudio.com as my TFS server and it opens fine if i am not signed in. But once i am trying to log in it opens blank, like browser is waiting for something (the same as for microsoft.com and skype.com). Something related to live ID?

Answer (score 0):

Don't think this is the website to post this kind of question but try uninstalling VS2013 preview because you think that's causing the problem. Search in Google for people getting similar problem. I also don't think it is VS2013 because I can't think of anyway of how VS2013 would somehow disable you from going to a certain website. Make sure the sites weren't down at the time or if you're having something kind of Internet server issues.

Comment: Did all the things you mentioned, neither helped. One interesting observation though, i am using tfs.visualstudio.com as my TFS server and it opens fine if i am not signed in. But once i am trying to log in it opens blank, like browser is waiting for something (the same as for microsoft.com and skype.com). Looks like something related to live ID.

Answer (score 0):

skype is owned by microsoft, so you can't enter both microsoft pages. This could be related with some kind of ISP (Internet Service Provider) and not with VS2013, or you can try rebooting your router. Last thing i would do is traceroute both address and see where they fall.

Comment: i am not sure i understand this statement "skype is owned by microsoft, so you can't enter both microsoft pages". I already traced the addresses, neither of them failed. It sure is machine related, since as i said i tried another PC with the same Ethernet connector and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to write this as a comment but I don't have enough reputation yet. Anyway, obviously trying to uninstall the program and trying again would be a good start as already mentioned, but you should also look inside your hosts file for any weird redirections some virus of malware might have set up. It's located at "C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc" and you can open this inside notepad (might require notepad to be run as an administrator). Check to see if skype.com or microsoft.com are in there and are pointing to a different IP address. If they are you can just remove them and save the file (might require a restart to take effect). If still no luck you should try a livecd of a linux distro to make sure the problem is definitely inside your windows somewhere.

Let us know how it goes.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning hosts file. Yes, i checked it and it was clean. The interesting thing is that i can access any web page accept ones of Microsoft. Have a suspicion that this is somehow LiveID related.